# exec python2 vs python3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm transferring a testframework from python2 to python3.
I have troubles with the exec statement to exec function change.
At run-time I decide depending on a xls file which function is called.
I tried to give local() and global() and also tried the execHelper instead of exec (see example below) I also tried the namespace technique of the exechelper function direct in the testfunction but always some names are not found in the namespace....
any suggestions?

```
def execHelper(command,callerobject):
    ns = {}
    exec(command,ns)
    for name, value in ns.items():
        setattr(callerobject, name, value)

def myfunction2(val1,val2):
    return val1 * val2

class myclass():
    def myfunction1(self,val1,val2):
        return val1 + val2

    def test(self):
        a = 5
        self.b = 10
        exec("result = self.myfunction1(a,self.b)+myfunction2(a,self.b)")
        print(result)


test = myclass()
test.test()
```

Comment: Why do you need exec there?

Comment: it is only an easy example to show the issue, of course I would not need that in that case. but with that example the problem is explained in the most easy way

Comment: Can you show the case where it does make sense to use it?

Comment: As above stated " At run-time I decide depending on a xls file which function is called" it is a testframework were developers adding input to an xls page. that xls page is used to generate tests.

Answer (score 0):

```
def myfunction2(val1,val2):
    return val1 * val2

class myclass():
    def myfunction1(self,val1,val2):
        return val1 + val2


    def test(self):
        a = 5
        self.b = 10
        exec("global result;result = self.myfunction1(a,self.b)+myfunction2(a,self.b)")
        print(result)


test = myclass()
test.test()
```

**Use global in exec function**

There is a big difference between exec in Python 2 and exec() in Python 3. 
So in python 3 , we have to bring the result varialbe into  the scope of exec().

Comment: sorry I thought I answered. It works with the global thing thanks a lot